# Vue router links do not render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building simple Vue app with routing. However, the links in template do not render and I get the error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

My index file is

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './Router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
})
```

Router, where I add two routes, is

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import ShowMap from './components/ShowMap'
import AddPointOnMap from './components/AddPointOnMap'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: ShowMap
        },
        {
            path: '/add',
            component: AddPointOnMap
        }
    ],
    mode: 'history'
})
```

App.vue is

```
<template>
    <div id="app" class="container">
        <div class="links">
            <router-link to="/">Map</router-link>
            <router-link to="/add">Add object</router-link>
            <a href="/">Map</a>
            <a href="/add">Add object</a>
        </div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>     

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app'
    }
</script>
```

ShowMap component is (AddPointOnMap is for now the same, but with name: 'AddPointOnMap')

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ShowMap',
        data: function () {
            return {
                map: null,
                tileLayer: null,
                layers: []
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.initMap();
            this.initLayers();
        },
        methods: {
            initMap() {
                this.map = L.map('map').setView([59.93863, 30.31413], 14);

                this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer(
                'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                {
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>',
                }
                );
                this.tileLayer.addTo(this.map);
            },
            initLayers() {

            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style>
    #map {
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>
```

The strange part is that router-view in App works okay, and moreover if I console.log router in index file it has two routes, which I added. But router-link elements do not render!

P.S. I relied on [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-vue-router) tutorial.

Comment: I guess the error comes from ShowMap component. Check that component for any name property and check if the object that has it is defined. Or you can post that component here too so we can check it.

Comment: @Allkin I updated the question

Comment: Where is your Leaflet Import?

Comment: at normalizeLocation (index.js:13083)

Comment: @Badgy it isn't imported, for now leaflet js just hangs in head element. But the map renders ok and works

Comment: I think the main problem is that you put the div with the id 'app' into your App component but Vue looks for that div to replace it with the App component. The div should live in your index.html.

Comment: @MátéWiszt thanks for noticing it, of cause you are right that it's fault but it's not the case either, I removed it from App and the problem remains

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine to me: I can see router links without any problems and they work as expected

Comment: @AlexEfremov Thank you. You are right. I just cross-checked all and I found that I started following one tutorial where vue was included on html page as script and then other where I used NodeJS. And in the end I forgot to remove vue as script and it conflicted)) So a stupid mistake from me!